# Sum only one column in a multi-dimensional list (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a 2D list as follows:

```
my_list=[[02/01/2018,2],[03/01/2018,5],...]
```

where the first element in each sub-list is a date and the second is a number.

How do I sum all of the numbers (the second elements) without using a `for` loop?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to fix the formatting and some grammatical errors. In the future, please format any code blocks you have by indenting it with 4 spaces or clicking the `{}` button after selecting some text - please see the [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for further information on formatting.

Comment: Use a list comprehension that only includes the second elements: `sum([sublist[1] for sublist in my_list])`

Comment: thank you Tomothy32. I will try to follow your advice.

Comment: thank you John Gordon, but your solution has a loop statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use numpy to do easily do this type of indexing and vectorized summing:

```
import numpy as np

my_list = np.array(my_list)
sum = np.sum(my_list[:,1]
```

Comment: thank you i will try your solution. i have to read for numpy since i haven't use it before